# need help in storing list in sqflite database from api using data model

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

response from api

```
{
"data": [
{
"title": "सात वर्षपछि मात्रै नागरिकता, नपाउन्जेल वैवाहिक परिचयपत्र !",
"description": "<p>काठमाडौं । विवाह गरेर भित्र्याइएकी विदेशी नागरिकको सम्बन्धमा सरकारले विभिन्न विकल्प अघि सारेको छ। विदेशी महिलाले नेपालीसँग विवाह गरेको ७ वर्षपछि मात्रै अंगीकृत नागरिकता पाउने भएका छन्। नागरिकता नपाउन्जेल वैवाहिक परित्रचयपत्र दिने प्रस्ताव अघि सारिएको छ।<br></p><p>संसद्को राज्य व्यवस्था तथा सुशासन समितिमा जारी नागरिकता विधेयकमाथिको छलफलमा सरकाले वैवाहिक अंगीकृत महिलाका हकमा नागरिकता प्रदान गर्ने सम्बन्धमा तीन विकल्प राख्दै यस्तो प्रस्तावसमेत गरेको हो। समितिमै भएका छलफललाई आधार बनाएर तीन विकल्प सुझाइएको छ।<br></p><p>समितिको शुक्रबारको बैठकमा गृह मन्त्रालयले पेस गरेको संशोधन मस्यौदामा विकल्पका रुपमा नेपाली नागरिकसँग विवाह गरेर आउने विदेशी महिलालाई ७ वर्षपछि मात्र अंगीकृत नागरिकता दिने प्रस्ताव गरिएको छ। त्यही प्रस्तावमा विवाह गरेर आएदेखि वैवाहिक अंगीकृत नागरिकता नपाउन्जेलसम्मलाई वैवाहिक परित्रचयपत्र दिने व्यवस्था गरिएको छ।<br></p><p>त्यस्तो परिचयपत्रमार्फत आर्थिक, समाजिक तथा सांस्कृतिक अधिकार उपयोग गर्न सकिनेछ। राजनीतिक अधिकार भने त्यो पत्रबाट प्राप्त गर्न सकिनेछैन। पत्रकै साहायताले कुनै पनि चुनावमा उम्मेदवार बन्न र मतदान गर्न भने पाइनेछैन।<br></p><p><br></p><p>विदेशबाट विवाह गरेर आएकी महिलालाई ७ वर्षपछि नागरिकता दिने तर राजनीतिक अधिकार भने त्यसको (नागरिकता पाएको) ७ वर्षपछि मात्रै पाउनेगरी सरकारले दोस्रो विकल्प पनि अघि सारेको छ।</p><p><br></p><p>त्यस्तै सरकारले अघि सारेको तेस्रो विकल्पमा नागरिकता ऐनलाई संशोधन गर्न बनेको विधेयकमा व्यवस्था भए बमोजिम नै गर्ने उल्लेख छ। विधेयकमा यस प्रावधान अनुसार नागरिक बन्न चाहने महिलाले नेपाली नागरिकता पाएको ६ महिनाभित्र विदेशी नागरिकता त्यागेको प्रमाण पेस गर्नुपर्ने उल्लेख छ। त्यसो गर्न नसकेमा नागरिकता स्वत: रद्द हुने व्यवस्था छ।</p><p><br></p><p>नेपाली महिलाले विवाह गरेर भित्र्याएका विदेशी पुरुषले भने अंगीकृत नागरिकता पाउन १५ वर्ष नेपालमा बसोबास गरेको हुनुपर्नेछ । साथै अन्य मुलुकको नागरिकता त्यागेको, असल चालचलन भएको र नेपाली वा नेपालमा बोलिने कुनैपनि भाषा बोल्न जानेको हुनुपर्नेछ।</p><p><br></p><p>गृहको नयाँ प्रस्ताव गर्ने समय चाहिने भन्दै कांग्रेस र तराई केन्द्रित दलका नेताले भने अध्ययनका लागि एक दिनको समय मागेका छन्। उनीहरुको माग अनुसारै आज त्यस विषयमा केही निर्णय गरी समितिको बैठक शनिबार बिहान बोलाइएको छ।</p><p><br></p><p>शनिबारको बैठकमा मस्यौदाको उक्त व्यवस्थासहित विधेयक प्रतिवेदन पास गर्ने समितिकी सभापति शशि श्रेष्ठले जानकारी गराइन्।</p><p><br></p><p>यही विषयमा कुरा नमिल्दा एक वर्षदेखि विधेयक अघि बढ्न सकेको छैन। नागरिकता ऐनका विषयमा संसदमा समेत कुरा उठ्न थालेपछि यही अधिवेशनबाट पास गर्ने लक्ष्य समितिको छ। संसद् आगामी असोज २ गतेसम्म मात्रै चलाउने तयारी संसद सचिवालयले गरेको छ।</p>",
"views": 977,
"author": null,
"created_at": "2019-09-13T14:34:48.000000Z",
"slug": "-1",
"image": "https://actpronepal.com/storage/photos/1/pm-oli-pokhara_BtXucYmTJ8.jpg",
"categories": [
{
"id": 2,
"name": "समाचार",
"parent_id": 0,
"slug": "news"
}
]
},
{
"title": "विमानस्थलमा ट्याक्सी सेवा सहज बनाउन तत्काल काम अघि बढाउनू-पर्यटनमन्त्री",
"description": "<p>काठमाडौं । संस्कृति, पर्यटन तथा नागरिक उड्डयनमन्त्री योगेशकुमार भट्टराईले त्रिभुवन अन्तर्राष्ट्रिय विमानस्थलमा सञ्चालन भइरहेका ट्याक्सीहरुको हालको गुणस्तरको मूल्यांकन गरी यात्रुहरुलाई सहजता दिन आवश्यक अध्ययन गर्न विमानस्थलस्थित सवारी पार्किङ अनुगमन कमिटीलाई निर्देशन दिएका छन्।&nbsp;<br></p><p>नेपाल नागरिक उड्डयन प्राधिकरण, विमानस्थल प्रशासनलगायतका सम्बद्ध पदाधिकारीसँगको छलफलमा मन्त्री भट्टराईले त्यस्ता ट्याक्सीहरुको गुणस्तर, मापदण्ड, भाडादर आदि विषयमा १ महिना भित्र प्रतिवेदन पेश गर्न निर्देशन दिएका हुन्।&nbsp;<br></p><p>मन्त्री भट्टराईले विमानस्थल स्थित ड्यूटी फ्रि पसल पूनः संचालनका निम्ति बिक्री गरिने सामानहरुको सूचीसहित विमानस्थल व्यवस्थापनवाट यथाशिघ्र पेश गर्ने र मन्त्रालयस्तरवाट सम्वन्धित निकायमा समन्वय गरी ड्यूटी फ्रि पसल संचालन को लागी पहल गर्ने पनि बताएका छन्।&nbsp;<br></p>",
"views": 597,
"author": null,
"created_at": "2019-09-13T14:41:12.000000Z",
"slug": "-2",
"image": "https://actpronepal.com/storage/photos/1/yogesh-bhattrai.jpg",
"categories": [
{
"id": 2,
"name": "समाचार",
"parent_id": 0,
"slug": "news"
},
{
"id": 5,
"name": "ट्राभल",
"parent_id": 0,
"slug": "travel-trekking"
}
]
},
]
```

data models for post and categories

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'category.dart';

class Post {
  Post({
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.slug,
    this.createdAt,
    this.views,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.authorName,
    this.categories,
  });

  String title;
  String description;
  String slug;
  String createdAt;
  int views;
  String imageUrl;
  String authorName;
  List<Category> categories;

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    //json['categories']=json['category']
    print("json value $json");
    // print("${json['categories']}");
    // List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json['categories'])
    //     .map((e) {
    //       print("testing $e");
    //  return Category.fromJson(e);
    // });
    // List<String> c = [];
    // json['categories'].forEach((Map<String, dynamic>element) {
    //   c.add(jsonEncode(element["name"].toString()));
    // });
    // print("list of categories testing: $c");

    return Post(

      title: json["title"],
      description: json["description"],
      slug: json["slug"],
      createdAt: json["created_at"],
      views: json["views"],
      imageUrl: json["image"],
      authorName: json['author'] != null ? json['author']: "",
      categories: json['categories'] != null ? List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json['categories'])
          .map((e) => Category.fromJson(e))
          .toList()
      :null,
      //categories: json['categories'] != null ?c : null,
    );
  }


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    List<String> c = [];
    categories.forEach((element) {
      //c.add(jsonEncode(element.toJson()));
      c.add(jsonEncode(element.toJson()));
    });
    return {
      "title": title,
      "description": description,
      "slug": slug,
      "created_at": createdAt, //.toIso8601String()
      "views": views,
      "image": imageUrl,
      "author": authorName,
      "categories": categories,
    };
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Category {
  int id;
  String name;
  int parentId;
  String slug;
  int position;
  int status;

  Category({
     this.id,
     this.name,
     this.parentId,
     this.slug,
  });

  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Category(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        parentId: json["parent_id"],
        slug: json["slug"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "parent_id": parentId,
        "slug": slug,
      };
}
```

and in the database i created the following

```
import 'package:flutter_act_pro_nepal/models/category.dart';
import 'package:flutter_act_pro_nepal/models/post.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = DatabaseHelper.internal();
  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;
  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db == null)
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  DatabaseHelper.internal();

  initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "actProNepalDB15.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDb;
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    //creating table
    String createPostQuery =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Post("
        " `title` TEXT NOT NULL,"
        "`description` TEXT NOT NULL,"
        " `slug` TEXT NOT NULL,"
        "`categories` TEXT ARRAY,"
        "`created_at` TEXT NOT NULL,"
        "`views` INTEGER,"
        "`image` TEXT NOT NULL,"
        "`author` TEXT NOT NULL);";

    await db.execute(createPostQuery);

    String createCategoryQuery =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Category("
        "`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        "`name` TEXT NOT NULL,"
        "`parent_id` INTEGER,"
        "`slug` TEXT NOT NULL);";

    await db.execute(createCategoryQuery);
  }
```

what am i trying to do is save data contents from api to db, where i want to save all the categories[name] as list of string in DB. But i am not being able to figure out how to convert list of categories to list of string in db.

Comment: do you just want to save the categories list in database , or data list object that has list  of categories as well.

Comment: i need to save all post along with categories["name"] as list of string.